# SML functions parameters

Tags: sml, smlnj

Condition:
when 1. list was longer than the 2.  list   Return Value :1
when  1. list had the same number of elements as the 2. list   Return Value : 0
when the 1. list was shorter than the w. list    Return Value : ~1

```
([1,2,4,5],[3,2,5]);
1

([1,2],[1,5]);
 0

([5],[8,2,3]);
~1
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the `length` function could be your friend in this case:

```
fun foo (xs, ys) =
    let
      val len_xs = length xs
      val len_ys = length ys
    in
      case (len_xs < len_ys, len_xs > len_ys) of
        (true, false) => ~1
      | (false, true) => 1
      | (false, false) => 0
    end
```

which will yield the results:

```
- foo ([1,2,4,5],[3,2,5]);
val it = 1 : int
- foo ([1,2],[1,5]);
val it = 0 : int
- foo ([5],[8,2,3]);
val it = ~1 : int
```

However this is both inefficient and ugly. So we can also just pull off one element from each of the list at a time until one of them (or both) gets empty:

```
fun bar ([], []) = 0
  | bar (_, []) = 1
  | bar ([], _) = ~1
  | bar (_ :: xs, _ :: ys) = bar (xs, ys)
```

Which gives the results:

```
- bar ([1,2,4,5],[3,2,5]);
val it = 1 : int
- bar ([1,2],[1,5]);
val it = 0 : int
- bar ([5],[8,2,3]);
val it = ~1 : int
```

Comment: Well at first, you might wan't to go read up on basic sml. Next you could put in what ever variable name you like, however that would be pointless.

Comment: I did not see usage of this anywhere. so I had to ask. sorry.

Comment: Well it is both for aesthetic purposes, but
also "performance". As I mentioned to you elsewhere, with the
wildcard the value will not be bound to the variable and thus
theoretically you save resources. However an interpreter/compiler
might be smart enough to do this optimisation anyways, and this
is where the aesthetic part also comes to play.

Comment: @ Jesper.Reenberg. Im sorry if you are bussy. but can you look at my new question and help me please?